# How to let a screen responsive, according to the monitor resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Good Morning!

I have a login screen, which I'm doing with bootstrap 4.

How would I adjust the layout of the page so that the background image is not missing or exploding.

As you can see in the image below, in monitors of 1440 x 1032 a bottom part of the background image is missing

[1440 x 1032 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Eux.png)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" type="text/css">
<div class="py-5" style="background-image: url('../Content/img/cover-stripes.svg'); background-position:left center; background-size: cover;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="p-5 col-lg-6">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Efetuar login.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
$enable-rounded:            true !default;
$enable-shadows:            true;
$enable-transitions:        true;
$enable-hover-media-query:  false;
$enable-grid-classes:       true;
$enable-print-styles:       true;

// Variables
//
// Colors

$theme-colors: (
  primary: #12bbad,
  secondary: #4f70ce,
  light: #f3f3f3,
  dark: #151515,
  info: #ccc,
  success: #28a745,
  warning: #ffc107,
  danger: #dc3545
);

$body-bg: white;
$body-color: #333;


$body-color-inverse: invert($body-color) !default;
$link-color: #12bbad;

// Fonts
$font-family-base: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
$headings-font-family: $font-family-base;
$display-font-family: $font-family-base;
$font-weight-normal: 200;
$headings-font-weight: 200;
$lead-font-size:   1.30rem;

$spacer: 1.5rem;

@import 'bootstrap-4.1.3';


html,body {
   height:100%;
}

.cover {
    min-height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center
}


.bg-gradient {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: color-yiq(map-get($theme-colors, 'primary'));
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, theme-color("secondary") 0%, theme-color("primary") 50%, theme-color("primary") 100%);
}

.filter-dark {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: color-yiq(map-get($theme-colors, 'dark'));
    &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    background: rgba(map-get($theme-colors, 'dark'), 0.75);
  }
}

.filter-light {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: color-yiq(map-get($theme-colors, 'light'));
    &:before {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    background: rgba(map-get($theme-colors, 'light'),0.75);
  }
}

.filter-color {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: color-yiq(map-get($theme-colors, 'primary'));
    &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    background: rgba(map-get($theme-colors, 'primary'), 0.75);
  }
}

.filter-gradient {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: color-yiq(map-get($theme-colors, 'primary'));
    &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg, transparentize(theme-color("secondary"), 0.1) 0%, transparentize(theme-color("primary"), 0.1) 50%, transparentize(theme-color("primary"), 0.05) 100%);
  }
}

.filter-fade-in {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    background: linear-gradient($body-bg, transparentize($body-bg, 0.2),transparentize($body-bg, 0.9),transparentize($body-bg, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `height: 100vh;` and for more details you can visit my https://codepen.io/jaydeeep/pen/vQJZda

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use width100vw and height:100vh
Vh is view height and vw is view width